# Angularjs ngClick to change another view

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a demo using Angularjs. Here is the [preview](http://jsfiddle.net/Witcher42/db9cZ/1/embedded/result/) of the demo.

In the demo, there is a list on the left. And there is also a list on the right. I need to change the **View** of the right list when I click on the item of the left list.

I use 2 `controllers` to control left list and right list. Every item of left list has a `ng-click` attribute to trigger the change of the right list.

So how to make the right list change?

Maybe, I should use a `controller` to control both the right and left list? (it seems not appropriate)

Maybe, I should `$watch` a parameter of the `$rootScope`? (too tricky)

At last, what's the suitable way to handle this situation? How to trigger the change of another controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should use `$broadcast(eventName, args)` to broadcast events from one controller to the other, where you would do a `$on(eventName, listener)` to handle those events.

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24broadcast)

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$on](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24on)